# An holomorphic function with zero real or imaginary part is constant

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to prove this proposition:

> Let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ a domain, such that $Re(f)=0$ or $Im(f)=0$. Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then $f$ is constant on that domain.

So I see that it's true, because I know that holomorphic $\implies$ analytic $\implies$ $C^1(\Omega)$. So we can say that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$, and then use CR equations.

But I haven't been proved the first implication yet, so I can't use the fact that we know that $f$ is $C^1$.

How can we prove this then?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does holomorphic mean to you?

Comment: Holomorphic means that $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable on every point of the domain.

Comment: What about analytic?

Comment: Is analytic on a point if we can put it as a power series on a neighbourhood of that point

Comment: OK. You don't need power series for this. It is a basic theorem of complex analysis that holomorphic functions are analytic. Write $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$. If $u$ is identically zero then $u_x$ and $u_y$ vanish. What do the CR equations tell you about $v_x$ and $v_y$?

Comment: That they vanish too, but I haven't been proved this (it's like 50 pages forward on my notes). I know this implication, but I can't use it here.

Comment: You don't require $C^1$ for the CR equations to hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\Re{f} = u$ and $\Im{f} = v$, so that $f = u+iv$.
If we assume that $f$ is holomorphic and that that $u = 0$, we get by the CR equations
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\\
0 &= -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.
\end{align}
Integrating the first equality w.r.t. $y$, we get
$$ v = g(x) $$
for some function $g(x)$. What does the second equality tell us about $g$?

Comment: Not sure why you're integrating. Both partials of $v$ vanish everywhere in a connected open set. Therefore $v\equiv 0$

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean $v=C$ where $C$ is a constant. Yes, of course one can say this directly, I just wanted to motivate how one can prove this.

Comment: Yes, $v\equiv C$ thank you

Comment: Actually, $v_y \equiv 0$ does not imply $v=g(x)$ for general connected domains.

Comment: Could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: Consider $\Omega = \{1<|z|<2\}.$ Define $v=1$ on $\{0\}\times (1,2),$ $v=0$ everywhere else.

Comment: And how exactly does that contradict the claim that $v=g(x)$?

Comment: $v(0,y)$ is not constant; it's $1$ at the top and $0$ at the bottom

Comment: But this then goes against the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic. The function $v$ should be $\mathscr{C}^1$.

Comment: It's easy to create a smooth version of this $v$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77902/discussion-between-sobi-and-zhw).

Answer (score 1):

If $f=u+iv$ is holomorphic in $\Omega,$ then the CRE hold in $\Omega.$ If we also know $u\equiv 0$ in $\Omega,$ then both partials of $u$ vanish everywhere. Hence, by the CRE, both partials of $v$ vanish everwhere. Since we are in a connected open set, this implies $v$ is constant in $\Omega.$ Thus $f(z) = iC$ in $\Omega$ for some real constant $C.$